The effect of the rollback migration on the database
I run [add-migration] command  4 times and create 4 migrations on my console Application (C#) code first project Initial, Secondary, Third and Forth Respectively. I run [update-database] command  After the execution of each[add-migration] command. in last migration (Forth), I add a new column to specific table and insert data to it from my code first program. now I rollback to Third migration and I want to delete that new column and its data automatically by executing the
update-database -TargetMigration:"Third"  command. But this is  doesn't affect my database.
I want to know if the method I'm going with matches what I expect it to do or not.

Check the generated migration files, it should contain the add column and remove column commands in the up/down methods. In EF core I think the -Migration flag is used to specify target migration. But the overall idea seem correct to me.
